# Group Sum Total by Year and Month

Tags: sql

I have a table in SQL that contains invoice data. The only 2 columns I care about are Amount and Date. I have several thousands of rows spanning several years

For example

```
19.32        2017-01-01 03:28:37.787
```

My query looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    YEAR(CreatedUtc) AS [Year],
    MONTH(CreatedUtc) AS [Month], 
    DATENAME(MONTH, CreatedUtc) AS [Month Name],
    SUM(InvoiceTotal) as [InvoiceTotal]
  FROM [dbo].[Invoice]
  GROUP BY YEAR(CreatedUtc), MONTH(CreatedUtc), DATENAME(MONTH,CreatedUtc)
) AS t

PIVOT (
  SUM(InvoiceTotal) 
  FOR [Month Name] IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],
    [June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],
    [December])) AS MNamePivot
ORDER BY 1,2
```

However, my results are close, but not exactly what I am looking for. How can I get all 12 months for each year on a single line?

```
Year    Month   January February    March   April   May June    July    August  September   October November    December

2013    10  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3803.15 NULL    NULL

2013    11  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4039.90 NULL

2013    12  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4498.70

2014    1   27139.45    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

2014    2   NULL    28164.61    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

2014    3   NULL    NULL    29185.82    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

2014    4   NULL    NULL    NULL    29933.51    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

2014    5   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    30470.01    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

2014    6   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    32100.82    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: If you only care about two columns, why are you selecting all? (`SELECT * FROM...`)

Comment: I meant to say I only care about the 2 columns from the invoice table. Sorry, wasn't clear.

Comment: @peterh thank you for editing this. Would love to know how you did that?

Comment: Your originally tagged `c#`, do you need a SQL solution or a LINQ solution?

Comment: @JCircio My pleasure :-) The editor has numerous formatting options, with the icon like `{}` you can convert the marked text to code formatting. You can always edit your own posts, others only over 2000 reputation. There is an "edit" link below your post, click this and you can edit it any time.

Comment: @JCircio Btw, it is always very important to indent your code better as you did :-) I reindented it for you, but your bosses, co-workers won't like this. And also you won't get so good answers on the StackExchange.

Comment: i think you don't need to include `MONTH(CreatedUtc) AS [Month]` in your final select so that it will aggregate the result into 1 line per year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the `MONTH(CreatedUtc) AS [Month]` from `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` in order to group by *Year* alone. And in fact, grouping by *Month* is redundant since you pivot by it in columns.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    YEAR(CreatedUtc) AS [Year],
    MONTH(CreatedUtc) AS [Month], 
    DATENAME(MONTH, CreatedUtc) AS [Month Name],
    SUM(InvoiceTotal) as [InvoiceTotal]
  FROM [dbo].[Invoice]
  GROUP BY YEAR(CreatedUtc), DATENAME(MONTH,CreatedUtc)
) AS t

PIVOT (
  SUM(InvoiceTotal) 
  FOR [Month Name] IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],
    [June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],
    [December])) AS MNamePivot
ORDER BY 1,2
```

See [Rextester demo](http://rextester.com/YQDJX52070) using random data.